# React-native version mismatch after upgrading to 0.60.4

Tags: android, react-native

After upgrading to react-native:0.60.4 I have been unable to run my app and I am getting a react-native version mismatch error while testing it both on a real device as well as on an emulator. When upgrading I have followed the rndiff that is commonly used for project setup and

After searching the repository for any mentions of 0.55.4 nothing outside of node_modules was found. I have attempted clearing caches or builds, reinstalling and brand new clones but nothing fixes this. As per previous issues, I have tried adding forced= true in build.gradle, as well as multiple ways of declaring the react-native version but it doesn't solve the issue.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "cheerio-without-node-native": "^0.20.2",
    "fbjs": "^1.0.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.3",
    "jsc-android": "^245459.0.0",
    "onesignal": "^0.1.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-elements": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-icons": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-share": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "mock-async-storage": "2.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

android/build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
              classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
                classpath("com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.2.0")


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
                maven {
                        url ("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
                }
            google()
                jcenter()
        }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}


import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *   enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
*/

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
play {
    track = 'production'
}
/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    playAccountConfigs {
        defaultAccountConfig {
            serviceAccountEmail = "gppauto@api-blabla.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                jsonFile = file("gplay.json")
        }
    }
    signingConfigs{
    }

    defaultConfig {
        playAccountConfig = playAccountConfigs.defaultAccountConfig
            manifestPlaceholders = [
            onesignal_app_id: 'blabla',
            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
            onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
            ]
            applicationId "com.app"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.1"
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')){
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                    storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                    keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                    keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
            pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    //    implementation project(':react-native-icons')
    //    implementation project(':react-native-share')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'

        if (enableHermes) {
            def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
            debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
                releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        } else {
            implementation jscFlavor
        }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
}
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

After running with react-native run-android this is the error message I am getting with build successful in terminal

[image]

Comment: make sure your libraries are updated and try updating the bundle or restart the terminal

Comment: Tried this multiple times, doesn't help.

Comment: Try running npm install after deleting node modules

Comment: Tried it many times, with deleting lock files, resetting caches and clean git clones and install but it doesn't help

Comment: check your libraries (dependencies) that you are using in my case it was a dependency that was using older version for react native causing this error. I resolved by updating the libraries.

Comment: I did a clean git clone. Before installing i removed all dependencies with lower react-native version such as react-native-elements. After installing the remaining dependencies i still get the same error on build. Doesn't seem to be related to that.

Comment: have you run unlink and then run the link commands?

Comment: I don't have anything linked. As per upgrading instructions everything has been unlinked since autolinking is a thing now.

Comment: have you updated your bundle for android?

Comment: make sure you are on the right path of the root project before running npm start

Answer (score 1):

**Use this :**

1. First of all uninstall app from your device
2. After this clean gradlew
3. close the Metro bundler and also terminal
4. Open terminal in the root of your project directory and run

> npm start -- --reset-cache

or

> yarn start -- --reset-cache

4. Open another terminal in the root of your project directory and run

> react-native run-android

**Hope it will work**

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help. After react-native run-android  on a clean terminal I still get the same version mismatch.

Comment: did u uninstall the app from device???if yes then please remove node_module folder and again install node_modules by yarn or npm install and Do again the above steps hope then it will work

Comment: Yep, uninstall, remove locks and node_modules, npm install and failed. Have done this over 10 times already.

Comment: Make sure that you run your metro bundler (react-native start) on the same- which you want to run on device/emulatoro

Comment: Do you mean run them from the same location? Of course

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your app/build.gradle

```
implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.60.4") { force = true }
```

Clean the build , remove node modules and do npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

just re-create your android emulator to any later version of your current emulator